# How to update a view using Ajax in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-mvc-ajax

I want to update my MVC3 view Using Ajax,

My Code is here [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17046564/how-to-add-update-panel-in-mvc-3)

Please tell me how i'll add Ajax in my code to update a content of HTML table

Answer (score 1):

The basic outline would be:

**Client Side**

1. Call a JavaScript function from your update button.
2. Within the JavaScript function, use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to make an AJAX call to
   an action method on the server.
3. On success, use the returned JSON to generate the updated HTML and update your containing `div`, probably using a jQuery selector and the `html()` method.

**Server Side**

1. Create an action method with a return type of `JsonResult`.
2. Retrieve whatever data it is you need from wherever.
3. Return the data using `return Json(myData)` (you may find it easier to use the [JSON.NET Newtonsoft](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) library to get more control over serialising your objects into JSON).

Have a Google into these various steps, completely overhaul your code and see how you get on.